# Get Accessor Function errors

Tags: java, get, accessor

bit of a newbie to java.  i tried to make a class, with several methods.  and separate the calculations from the variables.  i am getting an error that i don't understand.

i have a class, with several methods.  i declare a list of variables in one method and try to create getFunctions.  but i get an error "@" or enumBody expected.

code:

```
public class Calendar {

   protected void Display () {
   s_alarm=get.s_alarm;
   }

   private void calcAlarms() {
      int alarm1;

       public int get.s_alarm() { return alarm1; }
   }

}
```

Comment: What is `get.s_alarm()`? It appears to be a method, but where is it declared? Within another method? Is that legal? Please review method syntax and valid characters in method and variable names.

Comment: You can't have a method within a method.

Comment: I think you would benefit from working your way through Oracle's online Java tutorials.

Comment: i guess so.  like i said, i copied the program structure straight from a textbook.  i fixed it, by making all the variables class variables before the main function.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void calcAlarms() {
  int alarm1;

   public int get.s_alarm() { return alarm1; }
```

}

You have coded method inside a method. That is the reason for error.